# Next.js - Pull data at specific times

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working on NewsAPI and I have a small API limit. I want to set certain times during the day and the server calls the API at these times so that every person coming to my site does not make API calls. How can I do that? Thanks.

My code [from Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching):

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=blablabla`
  );
  const news = await res.json();

  if (!news) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { news }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
```

Although we cannot make calls at certain times in a day, I would like to at least put 6 hours between each call (i.e. 4 calls per day) and send this information to clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `revalidate` to regenerate the page every ~6 hours.

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  // get news here

  return {
    ...
    revalidate: 60 * 60 * 6,
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it do it for each client separately, or does it just do it for the server and send it to all clients?

Comment: getStaticProps regenerates the page on the server and it then serves that same page over and over again to all clients.  However after the revalidate period expires any client that requests the page will trigger a rerender before it's served to all clients again.

Comment: Thanks - I think that's what I was looking for.